# Vector space with matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Given:
$ V_{A,B} = \{a_0A^4+a_1A^3+a_2A^2+a_3A+a_4B | a_i \in \mathbb{R}\} $

$A = \begin{pmatrix}-5 & 5\\\ 5 & -5\end{pmatrix}$, $B = \begin{pmatrix}-8 & 0\\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

$M = \begin{pmatrix}10 & -10\\\ -10 & -6\end{pmatrix}$ , $N = \begin{pmatrix}2 & -10\\\ -10 & -6\end{pmatrix}$

**1. Prove that $V_{A,B}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.**

**2. Find $\dim V$ and 2 bases of $V_{A,B}$**

**3. If $M \in V_{A,B}$ / $N \in V_{A,B}$ find coordinates of $M$/$N$ relative to the bases found in 2.**

My solution:

1. (*)$ M_{2\times 2}(\Bbb R)$ is a vector space and $V_{A,B} \in M_{2\times 2}(\Bbb R)$.

   (**)

> $u = (a_0A^4+a_1A^3+a_2A^2+a_3A+a_4B) \in V_{A,B}$, $v =
> > (b_0A^4+b_1A^3+b_2A^2+b_3A+b_4B) \in V_{A,B}$,  $$a_i, b_i \in \mathbb{R}$$ $$u + v \in V_{A,B}? $$
> $$(a_0A^4+a_1A^3+a_2A^2+a_3A+a_4B+b_0A^4+b_1A^3+b_2A^2+b_3A+b_4B) \in V_{A,B}?$$
> $$((a_0+b_0)A^4+(a_1+b_1)A^3+(a_2+b_2)A^2+(a_3+b_3)A+(a_4+b_4)B)\in
>  V_{A,B}$$

(***)

> $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, $v = (b_0A^4+b_1A^3+b_2A^2+b_3A+b_4B) \in V_{A,B}$
>
> $$\lambda v \in V_{A,B} ?$$
>
> $$(\lambda (b_0A^4+b_1A^3+b_2A^2+b_3A+b_4B)) \in V_{A,B}?$$
> $$((\lambda b_0) A^4 + (\lambda b_1) A^3 + (\lambda b_2) A^2 + (\lambda b_3) A + (\lambda b_4) B) \in V_{A,B}?$$ $$\lambda a_i \in \mathbb{R}, \lambda a_i = b_i, b_i \in \mathbb{R} => v = (b_0A^4+b_1A^3+b_2A^2+b_3A+b_4B) \in V_{A,B}$$

From (*), (**) and (***)$\implies$ $V_{A,B}$ is a vector space over $\Bbb R$.

2. $\dim V = 2$ I think because the number of vectors in $V_{A,B}$ is 2 since the matrices are $2\times 2$.
   (I'm not sure if the vectors should be row or column vectors but I made them for row) The vectors should be:
   $$[(5000a_0 - 500a_1 - 5a_2 - 8a_3), (-5000a_0 + 500a_1 + 5a_2)]$$
   $$[(-5000a_0 + 500a_1+ 5a_2), (5000a_0 - 500a_1 - 5a_2)]$$.

**I'm not sure how to solve the rest of 2. and 3. Any help is appreciated!**

Comment: What does ∈> mean? You've used it 3 times in (**).

Comment: @MasB I put a blockquote and it messed things up and I didn't notice. Thank you, it's now fixed

Comment: What is **M/N**?

Comment: @QuantumSuperfield I meant interchangably, or finding both as in: "if M belongs to V find coordinates of M relative to the bases found in 2." AND "if N belongs to V find coordinates of N relative to the bases found in 2."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$2.$**

> $\dim V = 2$ I think because the number of vectors in $V_{A,B}$ is 2 since the matrices are 2x2.

Unfortunately, this does not make sense. The dimension of a finite-dimensional vector space is the number of elements of any basis of the vector space.

The set $\{A^4,A^3,A^2,A,B\}$ spans $V_{A,B}$, but is not a basis for $V_{A,B}$ because the set is not linearly independent. Indeed,
$$A^2=-10A \ ; \ A^3=100A \ ; \ A^4=-1000A.$$
Substituting this into $ V_{A,B} = \{a_0A^4+a_1A^3+a_2A^2+a_3A+a_4B | a_i \in \mathbb{R}\} $, we have
$$(*) \ \ \ \ \ V_{A,B} = \{(-1000a_0+100a_1-10a_2+a_3)A+a_4B | a_i \in \mathbb{R}\}=\{\alpha A+\beta B |\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}\}.$$
Since $\{A,B\}$ is linearly independent and spans $V_{A,B}$, then the set
$$\left\{A=\begin{pmatrix}-5&5\\5&-5\end{pmatrix},B=\begin{pmatrix}-8&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$
is a basis for $V_{A,B}$. Since the number of elements of such basis is $2$, then $\dim V_{A,B}=2$. I will leave it up to you to find another basis for $V_{A,B}$.

**$3.$** Note that $M\notin V_{A,B}$, because there is no $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb R$ such that
$$M=\alpha A+\beta B.$$
I will leave it up to you to solve the case of the matrix $N$.

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand how you found that basis and does it have anything to do with the substitution into $V_{A,B}$ above? Also is the length of the basis 2 because 2 matrices (A and B) are in it?

Comment: @Average_C_Enjoyer The result $(*)$ means that every element in $V_{A,B}$ is a linear combination of $A$ and $B$. Therefore, the set $\{A,B\}$ spans $V_{A,B}$. Moreover, you can check that $\{A,B\}$ is linearly independent.  Since the number of elements of such basis is $2$, then $\dim V_{A,B}=2$.

Comment: I get the impression, Average, that you do not know what "basis" means. I suggest you brush up on the definitions – you'll have no luck solving problems if you don't.

Comment: N also doesn't belong to the space right, because I can't find any solutions.

Comment: @Average_C_Enjoyer Yes, $N\notin V_{A,B}$.

Comment: Would {C=(1 0 0 1), D = (0 1 1 0)} also be a basis since they are linearly independent and span $V_{A,B}$? And M N still won't be in the vector space.

Comment: @Average_C_Enjoyer No, because $C\notin V_{A,B}$ and $D\notin V_{A,B}$.

Comment: @QuantumSuperfield why?

Comment: @Average_C_Enjoyer The result $(*)$ means that if $X\in V_{A,B}$, then $$X=\begin{pmatrix}-5\alpha+8\beta&5\alpha\\5\alpha&-5\alpha\end{pmatrix}$$ for some $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb R$. Use this fact to find a basis for $V_{A,B}$.

Comment: @QuantumSuperfield I dont understand where this comes from. And shouldn't it be $ -5 \alpha -8 \beta $?

Comment: @Average_C_Enjoyer Yes, you are correct. It should be $-5\alpha-8\beta$.